# how to by pass proxy to for the rest api call

Tags: robotframework

I am using robotframework and I would like know what can I do so that I can avoid going through the proxy? I am using Windows and I have made sure there are no proxy variables in environment variables. I am also connected via WI-FI  unlike others who are on LAN for who do not see issue with the GET request.

```
KEYWORD ${resp} = RequestsLibrary . Get Request session, /token, params=${user info}, headers=${HEADER}
Documentation:  
Send a GET request on the session object found using the

Start / End / Elapsed:  20180102 13:17:11.558 / 20180102 13:18:26.569 / 00:01:15.011
13:17:11.566    DEBUG   Starting new HTTP connection (1): proxy-sanfran 
13:17:11.577    DEBUG   http://proxy-sanfran:80 "GET http://localhost:9000/token?userName=test_user&password=test123 HTTP/1.1" 301 None 
13:17:11.586    DEBUG   Resetting dropped connection: proxy-sanfran 
13:18:26.566    DEBUG   http://proxy-sanfran:80 "GET http://10.138.37.40 HTTP/1.1" 503 787  
13:18:26.568    INFO    Get Request using : alias=session, uri=/token, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'} json=None   
13:18:26.568    INFO    ${resp} = <Response [503]>
```

Comment: With proxy envionrment variables I'm assuming you refer to: `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`. When running robot from the command line, you need to restart the command line after you changed the enviornment variables in the GUI. When on the command Line run `SET | FIND "HTTP"` to see if there are any environment variables still active/cached. If there are use `SET HTTP_PROXY=` and `SET HTTPS_PROXY=` to remove them. Run previous command to verify they're no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

try with setting environment variable

```
NO_PROXY = "localhost"
```